# How to use OpenBase SQL in Objective-c for iphone?

Tags: iphone, sql, objective-c, openbase

I trying to use OpenBase SQL in my code to save large amount of data. But I have one difficulty regarding this, I am not able to find the frameworks required for using OpenBase SQL in my code. I have found some coding part from the net but that is not working since no framework for OpenBase is added.

Can anyone help me with this...

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQLite or, better yet, CoreData.  SQLite can store tons of data quite handily and, better yet, it is built into the iPhone OS.

Unless OpenBase were to make a statically linkable library -- a .a -- available for the iPhone OS, you won't be able to use it.

Comment: thanx for ur reply...
But I am having one small problem with sqlite, when I am trying to fetch data from the databse 2nd time it shows me the same data. The data is not refreshed. I have already posted 1 question on this before but I was not able to find a way.Can u help me with this problem.

Comment: That isn't an issue with SQLite, but a bug with your code.... let me dig up your other question.

Comment: Your previous question was answered, and it was a bug in your memory allocation / deallocation.  If you are having additional problems, you should ask another question about that.